# Does Disney's Ducktales say "Ask About Illuminati"?

Tags: illuminati

Regardless of whether The Illuminati (plural of Latin illuminatus, "enlightened") is/was real or fictitious, many people online seems to be claiming that in one episode of Ducktales this scene appears:

[image]

In the corner of the image, one can read "Ask about illuminati".

For example this site has an [article](http://www.collective-evolution.com/2013/03/25/disneys-ducktales-exposed-ask-about-illuminati/) called **Disney’s Ducktales Exposed: “Ask About Illuminati”** where they make the claim:

> I’m not trying to prove the existence of the Illuminati with this article. I just wanted to point out a few interesting observations. This episode of Disney’s “Ducktales” was aired in the 1980’s.

And they point out the image, they also link to a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0NAheMXhAk) video showing the Ducktales scene, which seems to be the current source.

The publisher of the video (which received 300K views since 3 years), is receiving full advertisements from YouTube, and seems to be linking to for-profit-website, it does raise suspicions of whether this really happened in the show.

Other articles claiming the same thing: [here](http://dutchsinse.com/pay-no-attention-to-that-man-behind-the-curtain-ask-about-illuminati/) and [here](http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=83e_1343674397&comments=1)

I would like to know if this was really introduced by the producer, Disney.

Comment: If the source is Ducktales, and judging by the hat and glasses, then the picture probably shows Scrooge McDuck rather than Donald Duck. Also, if the TV series's producers did put in a minor visual gag on the optician's chart then so what? Who cares? Claim seems trivial to me.

Comment: Conspiracy theorists will create more conspiracies whether or not this inconsequential joke truly exists in the original TV show. That's what they do. Conspiracy theorists gonna theorise conspiracies. ;)

Comment: I think the problem @AE has is that it is entirely unclear what it would mean *if* the scene is originally from the TV series. You somehow seem to imply that this would strengthen the idea that the Illuminati exist, but I am not seeing why it would. If this is authentic (and I see no reason to believe otherwise), Occam's Razor suggest that the makers of Duck Tales decided to put in a nice, harmless easter egg for their adult watchers. Nothin' more to it.

Comment: @xLeitix, exactly. Thanks for clarifying. :) It seems unimportant whether the claim is true or false. Sure it might be important to people who are paranoid, but I'm having trouble seeing why a generic [reasonable person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasonable_person) would consider it anything more than a factoid about the existence (or not) of a trivial joke.

Comment: @georgechalhoub, if I understand the rules of the site correctly, the question to ask is [whether the claim is notable](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable), rather than whether my subjective opinion is inferior to your subjective opinion. One way to address the notability question - if I correctly understand the rules of the site - would be to find a mainstream source discussing the claim. The ['everyone should be allowed to ask everything'](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/894/22504) argument has a -5 score on meta, currently.

Comment: @georgechalhoub, are those sources really considered mainstream? It seems to me that anyone can post anything on a website or on YouTube, without any real quality control at all, but I'll leave that issue for other people with more experience on how previous sources have been evaluated here at Skeptics.SE.

Comment: @AE The video has a substantial number of views which indeed would likely make the claim notable. Isn't this question asking for original research though?

Comment: Scrooge McDuck is clearly rich and powerful enough to be a member of the Illuminati.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are [many](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cgx-i2HUjyU) [versions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_Iy0YUcs_I) of [Episode "Yuppy Ducks"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ft9z5iFBDgY) on youtube alone, along with some on [other video-sharing](http://www.trilulilu.ro/video-animatie/ducktales-3x13-yuppy-ducks) [websites](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x16qyvo_ducktales-s02e008-073-yuppy-ducks_fun), all of which show the exact same in-place (presumed) joke/easter egg.

Unless all those bored video editors have gone to a *lot* of trouble, I think we can safely say that the answer to your primary question:

> I just want to know if this is real or not.

Is almost certainly **YES**, this existed in the original airing of this particular episode of Duck Tales.

Comment: More evidence: I have checked the version on a original DVD and it had the same thing, so it is real.

Comment: When checking 2022, all of the links are all dead. I don't dispute the resolution, just a note.

Comment: @pinegulf I noticed the same, cant find any online sources currently